# React client side routing with NGINX

Tags: reactjs, nginx, react-router

I have a single page app made with react using NGINX for the reverse proxy. Problem is, every time I navigate to a new route it still triggers a page navigation event in the browser.

So the new route loads but it still causes the browser to load a new page which is a problem because I want to have and audio player and triggering a browser navigation event cuts off any audio playing. What's the ideal setup to make this work?